# laravel not reading autoload_classmap.php?

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm having problems in one of my dev environments that I thought I had tracked down to a problem with the `autoload_classmap.php` file, but now I'm not so sure. I'm having a hard time tracking it any further and, frankly, my experience with the laravel forums has been an absolute joke, so I thought I'd ask here.

Usually after I change git branches in my local development environment, I get the following error trying to load up my site:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Config\EnvironmentVariables' not found in /home/username/projects/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php on line 119

Call Stack:
    0.0000     231784   1. {main}() /home/username/projects/project-name/public/index.php:0
    0.0181    1464432   2. require_once('/home/username/projects/project-name/bootstrap/start.php') /home/username/projects/project-name/public/index.php:35
    0.0233    2006416   3. require('/home/username/projects/project-name/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/start.php') /home/username/projects/project-name/bootstrap/start.php:84
```

The class name changes every time I run the installation. Originally, I tracked the problem down to the fact that `composer dump-autoload` wouldn't update the `autoload_classmap.php` file to include any of the `Illuminate` classes. Once I figured out I needed to run `composer install` instead, I found those classes in the class map...but I'm still getting that error, despite that line showing up in my class map and pointing to the right location:

```
'Illuminate\\Config\\EnvironmentVariables' => $vendorDir . '/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/EnvironmentVariables.php',
```

I'm finally at the point where I can't seem to get my environment running at all. Last time this happened it took three separate times recreating my environment until things magically started working. Can anyone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot why files that are showing up in my classmap still aren't loading? Is there a log I can check? Is there some combination of composer commands I can run to get everything running?

Comment: Have you tried completely removing your vendor directory and running a fresh composer update?

Comment: Sort of. I have tried removing the vendor directory and running `composer install`, because we're version-locked for some packages in production and I don't want to stream in any new versions without a lot of regression testing. Sometimes this solves the problem, sometimes it picks up only `Illuminate` packages but not `Symfony` packages...no rhyme or reason, it seems.